# How do I make a generic method when the collection<T> needs genericizing?

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have two methods:

```
public Set<String> method1()
public List<String> method2()
```

How do I make a generic method off this? Specifically, I'm looking to genericize the "Set" and "List".

Here's an attempt that didn't work:

```
public static <T extends Collection> T<String> genericMethod
```

It's showing a compiler error: Type "T" does not have type parameters.

Comment: _why_ it did not work?

Comment: didn't get the question, do you want to handle constructing both set and list in a single method?

Comment: may be this `public static <T extends Collection<String>> T genericMethod()`, but this is _not_ limiting to `Set` or `List`, which you can't anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the signature goes, it would be

```
public static <T extends Collection<String>> T genericMethod() {
    ...
}
```

Presumably, `genericMethod` is going to create an instance of `T` at some point and return that, rather than just returning `null` (that wouldn't be very useful, would it?), but there is no guarantee that `T` has any constructors at all. And due to type erasure, the runtime wouldn't know what type to create anyway. To work around this, the method would also need to accept a parameter that tells it how to create a `T`:

```
public static <T extends Collection<String>> T genericMethod(Supplier<? extends T> tSupplier) {
    ...
}
```

Now, rather than saying `new T()`, which is invalid, you do `tSupplier.get()` to get a `T`.

If the caller wants a `Set<String>`, for example, they would do:

```
Set<String> set = genericMethod(HashSet::new);
```

Note that the specific implementation of the collection is now specified by the caller, rather than hidden as an implementation detail of `genericMethod`. This is inevitable, as the specific type of collection (`T`) is now unknown to `genericMethod`.

Comment: This is 100% what I needed. The caller was going to provide how to construct the returned objects. Thank you